# Is it possible to return all columns data of an entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible for a entity class

```
class mytest
{
    public int id {get;set;}
}
```

with Entity Framework to query this entity and get all its column out without them being present in the C# class?

Given a table I want to filter based on some columns I know is present and then return all the other columns still, in the case above I know the table as a id column.

Comment: No - if you load an entity in a class with only `id` - there's no way to get all the other columns. If you want all columns from the database, all fields corresponding to these columns have to be present in the C# class

Comment: No you can't, if that is what you want to do then EF is not really an appropriate tool. You can do that using ADO.net and DataTables.

Comment: Even if you got the generated SQL to return all of the columns, how would you reference them in the code?

Comment: Theres many ways to get that information into code, simply return the data as a dictionary of key,value. Could generate the class by reflection based on asking the db for the columns first ect. I see many possible options to get to an solution and was just wondering if someone else had done something similar or had a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have all the properties that you want materialised into your .Net code defined in the entity class, but you set an interface on the class to defined the "known" fields that you want to query on, such as ID:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use EF to query those defined fields, or you can use the generic methods on the EF context to query certain fields that every entity must have, such as Id:

```
context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
```

or

```
context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
```

The above assumes `TEntity : class, IEntity`